# The Harmonic Measures of Lucy Garnett

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, foliations, holomorphic-foliations

**The Harmonic Measures of Lucy Garnett**, *Alberto Candel*, Advances in Mathematics $176$ ($2003$) $187-247$.

Page $208$, Proposition $5.2$
I have actually two questions:

1. what does he mean by saying "$h(•,z)$ is $\Delta^*-$ harmonic on $D×\{z\}$"?
2. what does he mean by saying " $ vol_z(x)$ is the volume density of the plaque $D×\{z\}$"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means that $\Delta^* h(\cdot, z) = 0$.
2. It means that $ vol_z $ is the induced Riemannian volume on $ D \times z $.